# Getting the error "dtw() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dist'" while calculating dtw of 2 voice samples

Tags: machine-learning, dtw

I am getting the error "dtw() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dist'" while I'm trying to calculate the dtw of 2 wav files. I can't figure out why or what to do to fix it. I am attaching the code below.

```
import librosa

import librosa.display

y1, sr1 = librosa.load('sample_data/Abir_Arshad_22.wav')

y2, sr2 = librosa.load('sample_data/Abir_Arshad_22.wav')

%pylab inline

subplot(1, 2, 1)

mfcc1 = librosa.feature.mfcc(y1, sr1)

librosa.display.specshow(mfcc1)

subplot(1, 2, 2)

mfcc2 = librosa.feature.mfcc(y2, sr2)

librosa.display.specshow(mfcc2)

from dtw import dtw

from numpy.linalg import norm

dist, cost, acc_cost, path = dtw(mfcc1.T, mfcc2.T, dist=lambda x, y: norm(x - y, ord=1))

print ('Normalized distance between the two sounds:', dist)
```

the error is occurring in the 2nd last line.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is straight forward. Lets read the docs of the method you are calling:

https://dynamictimewarping.github.io/py-api/html/api/dtw.dtw.html#dtw.dtw

The dtw function has the following parameters:

> Parameters x – query vector or local cost matrix
>
> y – reference vector, unused if x given as cost matrix
>
> dist_method – pointwise (local) distance function to use.
>
> step_pattern – a stepPattern object describing the local warping steps
> allowed with their cost (see [stepPattern()])
>
> window_type – windowing function. Character: “none”, “itakura”,
> “sakoechiba”, “slantedband”, or a function (see details).
>
> open_begin,open_end – perform open-ended alignments
>
> keep_internals – preserve the cumulative cost matrix, inputs, and
> other internal structures
>
> distance_only – only compute distance (no backtrack, faster)

You try to pass an argument named **dist** and that argument simply is not known.

Instead, removing that argument would solve the issue, such as

```
dist, cost, acc_cost, path = dtw(mfcc1.T, mfcc2.T)
```